# How to configure tomcat 7 in Eclipse 3.6 with jdk 1.6.0_20?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I'm having some problems configure tomcat 7 on Eclipse 3.6 . The enviroment is a notebook with o.s. Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit.
Before this upgrade i work succesfully with tomcat 6 on Eclipse 3.6 but my switch on the newer tomcat is an evil! I repeat every instructions that I use to configure tomcat 6, but it doesn't works!

If I launch tomcat inside eclipse without monitored applications installed it works, as I add one application, it crashes.What I'm missing?

Here's tomcat log :

```
26-set-2010 2.02.24 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin;.;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\jre\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\10.0\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\putty;C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenLDAP\kfw\Binary;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\IDM Computer Solutions\UltraEdit\;C:\Program Files\SlikSvn
26-set-2010 2.02.25 org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
AVVERTENZA: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:DocSourcesProject' did not find a matching property.
26-set-2010 2.02.25 org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
GRAVE: End event threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.getObjectNameKeyProperties(StandardContext.java:5551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.setNamingResources(StandardContext.java:1757)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.getNamingResources(StandardContext.java:1735)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.SetNextNamingRule.end(SetNextNamingRule.java:99)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1058)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:601)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:180)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1343)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2755)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1544)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:515)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:551)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
26-set-2010 2.02.25 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
AVVERTENZA: Catalina.start using conf/server.xml: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:2688)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:2714)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1061)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:601)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:180)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1343)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2755)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1544)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:515)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:551)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.getObjectNameKeyProperties(StandardContext.java:5551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.setNamingResources(StandardContext.java:1757)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.getNamingResources(StandardContext.java:1735)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.SetNextNamingRule.end(SetNextNamingRule.java:99)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1058)
    ... 20 more
26-set-2010 2.02.25 org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
AVVERTENZA: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:DocSourcesProject' did not find a matching property.
26-set-2010 2.02.25 org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
GRAVE: End event threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.getObjectNameKeyProperties(StandardContext.java:5551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.setNamingResources(StandardContext.java:1757)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.getNamingResources(StandardContext.java:1735)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.SetNextNamingRule.end(SetNextNamingRule.java:99)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1058)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:601)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:180)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1343)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2755)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1544)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:515)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:564)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:415)
26-set-2010 2.02.25 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
AVVERTENZA: Catalina.start using conf/server.xml: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:2688)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:2714)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1061)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:601)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:180)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1343)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2755)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1544)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:515)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:564)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:415)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.getObjectNameKeyProperties(StandardContext.java:5551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.setNamingResources(StandardContext.java:1757)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.getNamingResources(StandardContext.java:1735)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.SetNextNamingRule.end(SetNextNamingRule.java:99)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1058)
    ... 20 more
26-set-2010 2.02.25 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
GRAVE: Cannot start server. Server instance is not configured.
```

Comment: Yes, i'm using WTP 3.2, the exact version is : 3.2.0.v201005241530-7b7GHTYFSK2W9kPaFClvz0O_NQmN
Build id: 20100615235519

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be an issue in WTP 3.2 in combination with Tomcat 7. This issue is also discussed in [this topic](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&goto=546852&) at the Eclipse forum. The cause and workaround is described as follows:

> It appears the startup process has changed in Tomcat 7 such that the
>   `<ResourceLink>`, when part of a `<context>` in server.xml, gets processed
>   before the server is sufficiently initialized. If you open the server
>   editor in Eclipse and **enable the "Publish module contexts to separate
>   XML files" option**, I believe you will avoid this issue. I'll see about
>   force enabling this option for Tomcat 7 servers in WTP 3.2.1.

Comment: Thanks, I will make a test enabling that option.

Comment: Thanks enabling "Publish module contexts to separate XML files" fix the issue.